# How do I formulate a specific formula for a sequence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

I have three arrays, for instance s = [1:2], j = [1:20] and b = [1:8], and I am trying to build a single row. 
The problem that I actually have is that I need to find a formula f(s,j,b) such that

f(1,1,1) = 1

f(2,1,1) = 2

f(1,1,2) = 3

f(2,1,2) = 4

f(1,1,3) = 5

f(2,1,3) = 6

...

f(2,20,8) = 320

What my first guesses were: (s * j * b), (s+j+b) of (s + (j-1) + (b-1)), but obviously these are wrong since (1,2,1) (2,1,1) (1,1,2) will all correspond to the same entry. How should I formulate a formula such that I get the desired outcome?

Comment: what would $f(1,2,1)$ be?

Comment: f(1,2,1) would be 17

Comment: Maybe it is useful to show more: f(1,1,1) = 1,
f(2,1,1) = 2,
f(1,1,2) = 3,
f(2,1,2) = 4,
f(1,1,3) = 5,
f(2,1,3) = 6,
f(1,1,4) = 7,
f(2,1,4) = 8,
f(1,1,5) = 9,
f(2,1,5) = 10,
f(1,1,6) = 11,
f(2,1,6) = 12,
f(1,1,7) = 13,
f(2,1,7) = 14,
f(1,1,8) = 15,
f(2,1,8) = 16,
f(1,2,1) = 17,
f(2,2,1) = 18,
f(1,2,2) = 19, 
f(2,2,2) = 20, 
f(1,2,3) = 21, 
f(2,2,3) = 22,
f(1,2,4) = 23,
f(2,2,4) = 24,
f(1,2,5) = 25,
f(2,2,5) = 26,
f(1,2,6) = 27, 
f(2,2,6) = 28, 
f(1,2,7) = 29, 
f(2,2,7) = 30, 
f(1,2,8) = 31,
f(2,2,8) = 32,
f(1,3,1) = 33,
f(2,3,1) = 34,
and so on

Comment: $$f(s,j,b) = 1 + (s-1)+2(b-1)+16(j-1) = s+2b+16j-18$$ Basically, you have $f(s,j,b) = 1$ when $s = j = b = 1$. Every increase of $1$ in $s$ changes $f$ by $1$. Every increase of $1$ in $b$ changes $f$ by $2 = \dim s$ and finally, every increase of $1$ in $j$ changes $f$ by $16 = \dim s \times \dim b$.

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't make a difference if j can range from [1:30] or [1:40] right, if I let s and b to be same?

Comment: If $j$ is the "outermost" index, its range didn't matter.  For $s$ and $b$, as long as you use the correct number of $\dim s$ and $\dim b$, everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f(s,j,b)=1+(s−1)+2(b−1)+16(j−1)=s+2b+16j−18